# The method read(String, String) is undefined for the type JsonPath

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonpath

am using the below code get the value from json file using jsonexpression, iam unable to use Jsonpath.read method getting pop saying that **The method read(String, String) is undefined for the type JsonPath**

```
    try {
        BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("C:\\Users\\****\\eclipse-workspace\\json_files\\jsonfile\\db-AAPL.json"));
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        String jsoncontent = builder.toString();
        JSONArray  array=JsonPath.read(jsoncontent,"$.response.data.arrayRowData[1].header.headerId");
        System.out.println(array.get(0));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: which library you are using for JSON support?

Comment: @Pavel using Json.simple, json-path

Comment: What version of JsonPath are you using? Did you check you've imported the correct class?

Comment: @Thomas i am using 5.2.0

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're using `com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath`? That class has `read(String, String, Predicate...)` but the version is only 2.7.0. The other library I found that has a version 5.2.0 is Rest Assured which has [`io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/json-path/5.2.0/io/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html) but not the method you want to use.

Comment: @Thomas After changing the version i am able to access the method thx

Answer (score 0):

After changing the json path verion to 2.7.0 able to access the Jsonpath.read method